# Preventing direct access to my HTML page

Tags: php, html, redirect

I'm currently working on a Contact Us page (contact.html). The sending of email is handled by a php file (mailer.php). So far, the functions I want to do is working properly, the emails are being sent, i get redirected to my success page and all. However, I want to restrict people from accessing my success page directly.

In mailer.php, i redirect by using this code:

```
header('Location: success.html');
exit;
```

How can I prevent users from directly accessing that page by entering the address to the address bar?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use sessions. But you have to change your html file to php so that your success page can check for session values to handle restricted access.

Comment: You can check with session. set some flag and check if it's true then user can access the page.

Comment: First, you need to use the POST method for the form instead of GET and then use the CSRF token to prevent the direct access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to convert your html page to php then you can set a session variable in your contact us page and then when the mail is successfully sent to the user then you can check for the this session variable's value to decide weather to redirect the user or not.

Suppose this is your contact us page.

```
<?php
    // code for sending mail
    if(the mail is sent successfully then)
    {
      $_SESSION["redirect_to_success"]=true;
    }
?>
```

This can be the code on the success page

```
<?php
  if(!isset($_SESSION["redirect_to_success"]))
  {
     header("location:contactus.php");
  }
  else
  {
    unset($_SESSION["redirect_to_success"]);
  }
?>
```

Here unseting the session variable allows the use to redirect to the success page only when the mail is sent successfully. Once he/she is redirected to the success page the session variable will be unset. And also using Boolean values allows less consumption of memory

Comment: after the line ' $_SESSION["redirect_to_success"]=true;' am i supposed to call success.php?

Comment: so i called success.php after setting the session value however, it seems like the session value isnt being saved since im always redirected back to the contact page even if i receive an email

Comment: UPDATE: I solved my problem by adding session_start(); on top of both of the php files. Thanks for the help!